# getting periodic error on asp.net website: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for fluorinefx/settings

Tags: c#, fluorinefx

I'm getting the error below periodically on my asp.net web app that is using fluorinefx as a communicator between flex and sql server 2008 database:
I'm using Flex 4.6, Fluorinefx runtime version 2.0.50727; .net framework 4.0

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for fluorinefx/settings: Could not find file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\5lggbw23.dll'. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Prop84\web.config line 29)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at FluorineFx.Configuration.FluorineConfiguration.get_Instance()
   at FluorineFx.FluorineGateway.Init(HttpApplication application)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

Any idea of what is causing this error?  It cant seem to find the file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\5lggbw23.dll'?

The frustrating thing is that the error seems to come and go

Comment: Intermittent errors are very hard to debug indeed. Do you have a load balancer set up and may be more than one web servers that are out of sync? Is there an App Pool recycle set up?

Comment: There is only one server.  The recycle interval is 1740 minutes -- would I benefit by creating a shorter interval?

Comment: Its been two days and fortunately I havent had the error repeat.  I was working with application pools at the time and might have inadvertantly changed the app pool